# Where are Azure Crash Dumps located?

Tags: azure-storage, autoscaling, wasabi

I have uploaded a hosted service to Azure. I am running a web role and a worker role. The autoscaling block is within the worker role. In Azure storage it automatically created a container called wad-control-container. The autogenerated blob has the following Directory Configuration

```
<DirectoryConfiguration>
      <Path>C:\Resources\directory\3a77c22456b2433890e2976e6621724d.WorkerRole1.DiagnosticStore\CrashDumps</Path>
      <Container>wad-crash-dumps</Container>
      <DirectoryQuotaInMB>1024</DirectoryQuotaInMB>
    </DirectoryConfiguration>
```

Why is it creating a local path? I do not have a container called wad-crash-dumps. Where can I find the crash dump created by the diagnostic monitor?